# GCC: instrument only non-inlined functions

Tags: gcc, profiling

I'd like to instrument a cyclic realtime app with `-finstrument-functions`, to measure where it spends its time (I cannot use a traditional profiler, since only specific cycles fail; I want to store execution traces of different cycles, and only retain those where the cycle time is not kept). However, `-finstrument-functions` instruments all functions. For small inline functions (getters and setters) this greatly distorts the performance characteristics of the code. How can I instrument only non-inline functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like GCC currently has no option to do this: see the feature request at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28205.
Clang, however, does have an option for this: `-finstrument-functions-after-inlining`. See https://reviews.llvm.org/D39331.